# How to use PulsarIO.write from Apache Beam in pipeline (Missing required properties: clientUrl)

Tags: java, apache-flink, apache-beam, apache-pulsar

I have a beam pipeline where I want to write the output to a pulsar topic.

In the end I say

```java
    pCollection.apply("Send to Pulsar", PulsarIO.write().withClientUrl(pulsarClientUrl).withTopic(pulsarTopic));
```

But during the startup it comes up with an exception of

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing required properties: clientUrl
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.pulsar.AutoValue_PulsarIO_Write$Builder.build(AutoValue_PulsarIO_Write.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.pulsar.PulsarIO.write(PulsarIO.java:148)
    at de.spx.bucketdataflow.PulsarTarget.main(PubSubToGcs.java:127)
```

After debugging, I come to the `AutoValue_PulsarIO_Write$Builder.build()` but there it is quiet simple.

```
        PulsarIO.Write build() {
            if (this.clientUrl == null) {
                String missing = " clientUrl";
                throw new IllegalStateException("Missing required properties:" + missing);
            } else {
                return new AutoValue_PulsarIO_Write(this.topic, this.clientUrl);
            }
        }
```

The check goes to the clientUrl which normally would get set in the next step of the builder pattern of `PulsarIO.write().withClientUrl`

Or am I handling it wrong?

I've tried beam-sdks-java-io-pulsar version 2.47 and 2.53
Both the same.

Thanks for hinting out!

-Tom

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `pulsarClientUrl` variable enclosed in your `.withClientUrl()` has the correct and valid Pulsar broker URL as it is a required component in the [`PulsarIO.write()`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/pulsar/PulsarIO.Write.html) class and it is the one triggering the "Missing required properties: clientUrl" error message.

The `AutoValue_PulsarIO_Write` is a necessary class configuration that writes data to the Pulsar topic through the Pulsar IO connector. Its property `this.clientUrl` feeds on the same variable `pulsarClientUrl`.

Not sure if he is the same Tom as you but submitting a bug in [GitHub (#30152)](https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/30152) is a good start in seeking assistance to resolve this and hopefully be included on the next [release](https://github.com/apache/beam/releases/tag/v2.53.0).

Comment: Wasn't possible for me to solve it in Beam style. Have migrated the whole flow to Apache Flink which works fine without any stunts.